# std::tuple with non moveable/copyable type

Tags: c++

Assume I have a struct `MyStruct` which contains a `std::mutex` and only reference or pod members. I want to create a `std::tuple` containing this type. But as `MyStruct` is not copy- or moveable it doen't work. It is working if I add a move constructor in the following way:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

struct MyStruct {
        std::vector<double>& vec_;
        int number_;
        std::mutex mutex_;

        MyStruct(std::vector<double>& vec, const int number)
           : vec_(vec), number_(number) {}
        MyStruct(MyStruct&& o) : vec_(o.vec_), number_(o.number_)
        {
                std::lock_guard guard(o.mutex_);
        }
};

int main()
{
        using T = std::tuple<MyStruct,int>;

        std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3.};
        T t{MyStruct{v, 1}, 2};
}
```

Is this safe? In the end I only want to construct it inside the `std::tuple` before any multi-threading is going on, but how can I ensure that the elements of the `std::tuple` are not moved once the `std::tuple` is constructed? Or is there a way to construct a `std::tuple` in place?

Comment: afaik, you can construct a pair in-place, not a tuple

Comment: Won't `auto tuple = std::make_tuple<MyStruct, int>({v, 1}, 2);` work?

Comment: Not with gcc 8.2.0.

Comment: g++ 8.2.1 accepts it - but I'm not sure it's really constructed in-place.
Btw, do you really mean to have a reference to the vector of doubles?

Comment: Also, moving a mutex is ok, so you could probably just `delete` the copy ctor and copy assignment operator and make the move ctor and move assignment `default`.

Comment: With `std::pair` you can write `std::pair<MyStruct, int> t(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(v, 1), std::make_tuple(2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code may be safe in particular circumstances, but if you want it to be safe in general, then you need to fix up your move constructor.  The move constructor must properly synchronize access to the moved-from object's state, and it must prevent that object from modifying the state once the new object has stolen it:

```
class MyStruct {
  std::vector<double>* vec_; // use a pointer here, not a reference
  int number_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
public:
  MyStruct(std::vector<double>& vec, const int number)
     : vec_(&vec), number_(number) {}
  MyStruct(MyStruct&& o)
  {
    std::lock_guard guard(o.mutex_);
    vec_ = std::exchange(o.vec_, nullptr);
    number_ = std::exchange(o.number_, 0); // doesn't necessarily have to be 0 here
  }
};
```

You will also have to change any other methods to account for the moved-from state.  Also note that I've changed this to a class and made the state private.  Having a public mutex and public data members invites trouble.  For safety, you must ensure that all access to the mutable state is properly synchronized.

**Without the Move Constructor**

If you want to avoid the move constructor, then the most obvious solution is to avoid using a `tuple`.  `tuple` is intended for use with generic code in libraries.  Valid uses in other contexts exist but are rare.  Consider using a struct to store the values instead:

```
struct Fixture
{
  MyStruct a;
  int b;
};
```

This has the advantage of naming your members (which is more readable) and allowing custom constructors.

**Using a std::tuple**

If you absolutely must use a tuple, then the problem is still solvable.  You just need a way to construct your `MyStruct` object after the tuple is constructed.  There a few ways you might do that.  Here are two:

Use `std::optional`:

```
int main()
{
  using T = std::tuple<std::optional<MyStruct>,int>;

  std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3.};
  T t{std::nullopt, 2};

  std::get<0>(t).emplace(v, 1);
}
```

Define a default constructor and use two-phase initialization:

```
// Add a constructor like the following, once again using a pointer instead of reference
MyStruct() : vec_(nullptr), number_(0) {}

// Add an init method
void init(std::vector<double>& vec, int number)
{
  vec_ = &vec;
  number_ = number;
}

// Later
int main()
{
  using T = std::tuple<MyStruct,int>;

  std::vector<double> v{1., 2., 3.};
  T t{MyStruct{}, 2};

  std::get<0>(t).init(v, 1);
}
```